# Como puedo evitar que cuando estoy trabajando con las opciones del menú de una ventana secundaria (toplevel) aparezca encima la ventana principal

Tags: python

Estoy realizando un programa con entorno grafico tkinter y dos módulos, el principal (main.py) y el secundario (editor.py), el programa en si funciona correctamente, pero cuando llamo una opción del menú de la ventana secundaria (editor), siempre aparece en primer plano la ventana principal, sé que esto se puede arreglar con el método “transient” de la ventana, pero no sé cómo pasarle la referencia a la ventana principal. Creo que la sintaxis seria:

```
self.transient(master=”ventana_principal”)
```

He intentado hacerlo así:

```
self.transient(master=tk.Tk)
```

Pero no funciona.

**Pregunta:**

¿Sabéis que y como se debería pasar el argumento a “master” para hacer referencia a la ventana principal?

El código seria el siguiente: Principal (main.py)

```
import tkinter as tk
from editor import Editor


class Menu(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Python")
        self.geometry("600x600+300+50")
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.salir)
        self.configure(background="honeydew")

        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self)
        self.filemenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(menu=self.filemenu, label="Archivo")

        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Abrir Editor", command=Editor)
        self.filemenu.add_separator()
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Salir", command=self.salir)


        self.mensaje = tk.StringVar()
        self.mensaje.set("Bienvenido al programa")
        self.monitor = tk.Label(self, textvar=self.mensaje, justify='left')
        self.monitor.pack(side="bottom", anchor="w")
        self.config(menu=self.menubar)

    def salir(self):
        self.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_win = Menu()
    main_win.mainloop()
```

Secundario: (editor.py)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import colorchooser as ColorChooser
from tkinter import messagebox as MessageBox


class Editor(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.title("Mi Editor")
        self.wm_state("zoomed")
        self.transient(master=tk.Tk)  # **No funciona**
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.salir)
        self.configure(background="honeydew")
        self.iconbitmap("casa.ico")

        # Barra de menu
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self)
        self.filemenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(menu=self.filemenu, label="Archivo")
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Cambiar color de fondo...",
                                  command=self.cambiar_color_fondo)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Cambiar color del texto...",
                                  command=self.cambiar_color_text)
        self.filemenu.add_separator()
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Salir", command=self.salir)

        # Crea Scrollbar
        self.scroll_ver = tk.Scrollbar(self)
        self.scroll_ver.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        # Caja de texto central
        self.texto = tk.Text(self, yscrollcommand=self.scroll_ver.set)
        self.texto.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
        self.texto.config(bd=5, relief="raised", padx=6, pady=4,
                          font=("Consolas", 12))

        self.scroll_ver.config(command=self.texto.yview)

        # Crear una barra de estado en la parte inferior de la ventana.
        self.mensaje = tk.StringVar()
        self.mensaje.set("Bienvenido a tu Editor")
        self.monitor = tk.Label(self, textvar=self.mensaje, justify='left')
        self.monitor.pack(side="left")
        self.config(menu=self.menubar)

    def cambiar_color_fondo(self):
        self.mensaje.set("Cambar el color de fondo")
        color = ColorChooser.askcolor(title="Escoje un color para el fondo")
        color = color[1]
        self.texto.config(bg=color)

    def cambiar_color_text(self):
        self.mensaje.set("Cambiar el color del texto")
        color = ColorChooser.askcolor(title="Escoje un color para el texto")
        color = color[1]
        self.texto.config(fg=color)

    def salir(self):
        resultado = MessageBox.askyesno("Salir",
                                        "¿Está seguro que desea salir?")
        if resultado:
            self.destroy()
```

También tengo la siguiente duda:

Cuando ejecuto el programa por primera vez no aparece ningún mensaje en el terminal, pero cuando lo cierro y lo vuelvo a ejecutar aparece el mensaje:  ” Reloaded modules: editor” y a partir de ahí cada vez que lo ejecuto aparece el mismo mensaje, ¿Es un error o es solo información?,  ¿Si es un error, hay alguna manera de evitarlo?.

Os agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda que me podáis dar.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema si no he entendido mal, no es  la ventana principal, es que tanto los `ColorChoser` como el `MessageBox` tienen el padre equivocado...

**En tkinter si no se le pasa un padre al inicializador del widget, por defecto su padre es la ventana principal**, la instancia de tkinter.Tk, incluidas las variables, como `StringVar`.

Como el padre de tus `ColorChoser` y el `MessageBox` es la instancia de `Menu`, cuando, el foco cae en ellos traen indirectamente al frente la ventana principal. La solución es usar el argumento `parent` y pasar la instancia de `Toplevel` como padre, que es la que debe ser:

```
color = ColorChooser.askcolor(
    parent=self, title="Escoje un color para el fondo"
    )
```

---

```
color = ColorChooser.askcolor(
    paren=self, title="Escoje un color para el texto"
    )
```

---

```
resultado = MessageBox.askyesno(
    "Salir", "¿Está seguro que desea salir?", parent=self
    )
```

En cuanto a `transient`, debes pasar una referencia al padre de la ventana `Toplevel`, en tu caso la instancia de `Menu`:

```
self.transient(master=parent)
```

pero volvemos a lo mismo, **pasa siempre un padre a todo widget que exista de forma explícita** te evitarás dolores de cabeza, al crear la ventana `Toplevel` en `Menu` no lo haces:

```
self.filemenu.add_command(label="Abrir Editor", command=Editor)
```

cambialo por:

```
self.filemenu.add_command(
    label="Abrir Editor",
    command=lambda: Editor(self)
    )
```

Con los cinco cambios todo debería ir bien. También puedes ocultar directamente la ventana principal mientras la secundarias está abierta si lo deseas.